# Open new html page with express server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a login page with 2 buttons. I want that when I click on the register button, a new html page (register.html) will open. All the files are located in the same folder.

What I tried so far:
My **index.html** file (main page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
        <script src="JS.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="login"> 
            User Name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" id="password"><br><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="loginUser()" value="Login"></button>
        <input type="button" onclick="RegisterUser()" value="Register"></button>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var lastResult = '';
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/')));

app.get('/register',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('/register.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Javascript file:**

```
function RegisterUser() {
    $.get("/register", function(res){

    });
}
```

And there is also the register,html file which I want to open after click.
I tried to create a "RegisterUser()" function on the JS file that calls to get function on the server.
I'm kind of new in all the node.js, express server world. Please correct me if it isn't the right way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean open ? Like you want to go to a new page ? Either way why don't you just use an anchor tag instead of a button ? Replace `<input type="button">....` with `<a href="/register">Register</a>` and then style the anchor tag appropriately so it matches your other button.

Answer (score 1):

> I want that when I click on the register button, a new html page (register.html) will open

You are making an Ajax request and then doing nothing with the data the server sends.

If you want to open a new page … just use a link.

```
<a href="/register">Login</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work man. it just transfer me to "file:///C:/register" (the file located in other folder) and even if I move it to C it doesn't open it.

Comment: @Ohad121 — That's because you loaded `index.html` directly from your disk instead of from the Express webserver.

Comment: Can you explain how I will be able to run this locally?

Comment: Umm. `node server.js`

Comment: Thanks it works. But how I do it with a button click?

Comment: @Ohad121 — Buttons are for submitting forms and running JavaScript. You need a link. You can apply CSS if you want it to look like a button. (Not recommended, looking link a button suggests to the user that it isn't just a link and will *do* something)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to redirect the user to another page without using an `<a>` element, you can use javascript!

There are two ways to do this, one simulates the user clicking on an `<a>` tag and then creates the new link, the other one simulates a http redirect.

The bonus to simulating a user click is that the user can then use the back and forward buttons of their browser to navigate between pages.

Here is how to simulate a click:

```
window.location.href = 'your link'
```

If you want to simulate a http redirect:

```
window.location.replace('your link')
```

If you want to get files off of your local server (folder) then simply call upon that file, it would look like this:

```
window.location.replace('register.html`)
```

Note, this only works with a front-end script without the need of jQuery. If you want this to work in the back-end, then you are going to require another plugin for node.js called socket.io. With socket you can allow the client to call upon the server to perform functions. You can read more about it here: [socket.io](http://socket.io)

I do not think it is a good idea to use your server.js file which is hosting the server to also perform functions for the client in the front-end. I usually have two files, `index.js` which is my server file and is what node.js reads, and then I have `client.js` which is what is sent to the client. It just helps keep things a bit more simple.

Comment: I want to build a web application. I'm not suppose to open the new page with the server somehow? thanks

Comment: @Ohad121 You can use the server script to open a new web page, I think. If you use `socket.io` you can ask the server to redirect the user to a new page. Without `socket.io` it is much harder to communicate between clients and the server. I have linked it if you want to take a look.

Comment: @Ohad121 Also the reason why your code doesn't work is because your javascript file is not communicating to the server file. In order to do that, check out socket.io. There you can emit a request from the client to tell the server to perform a certain task. Then you could either tell the server to send back a response or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could just change the `onClick` property of the register button to direct the browser to the register page, your js server would then send the html file.

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:3000/register')" value="Login"></button>
```

The above will open it in a new tab, to redirect from the current tab use:

```
<input type="button" onClick="location.href='http://localhost:3000/register'" value="Login"></button>
```

Replace localhost with your IP if you are not running the app locally, hope this helps!

Comment: That won't work. Absolute URLs have to start with a scheme (and there is no reason to use an absolute URL in the first place anyway).